# Shiny page title and image

Tags: r, shiny

My UI code is the following:

```
ui <- navbarPage(
theme = shinytheme("paper"),
title = div(img(src="ballerlablogo.png", style="margin-top: -14px;", height = 50)),

...

)
```

which works well, but then the title on webpage tab looks like this:

[image: tab title]

is there a way to have the page title be "Baller Lab" without getting rid of the image in the navbar or adding the "baller lab" text in the navbar?

Here is a link to the site: BallerLab.us

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `fluidPage` you can use `tags$head` to modify the title on the webpage tab

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("paper"),
  tags$head(HTML("<title>Baller Lab</title>")), #Without company logo
  #tags$head(HTML("<title>Baller Lab</title> <link rel='icon' type='image/gif/png' href='ballerlablogo.png'>")), #WIth company logo
  navbarPage(title = div(img(src="ballerlablogo.png", style="margin-top: -14px;", height = 50))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Without mixing Shiny functions and `HTML`: `tags$head(tags$title("My Title"))`

Comment: @Kalaschnik what if you want to add a title with a logo?

Comment: @a-suliman last time I checked the title element does only allow unicode plain text. However, this allows to add emojis: `tags$head(tags$title(" My Title"))`

Comment: @Kalaschnik the second option which is commented allows for adding a logo.

Comment: @a-suiman Aha, we are talking about favicons! I thought you want to place an image within the title element! Well, you could also stack the favicon in a nested R function:
`tags$head(tags$link(rel = "icon", type = "image/gif/png", href = "ballerlablogo.png")),
  tags$head(tags$title("Baller Lab"))`