# Shiny: How to change the page/window title in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

There are numerous posts regarding changing titles of other pieces of Shiny apps, e.g.:
[Change the title by pressing a shiny button Shiny R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060893/change-the-title-by-pressing-a-shiny-button-shiny-r)
[Shiny page title and image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688463/shiny-page-title-and-image)
[Shiny App: How to dynamically change box title in server.R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549235/shiny-app-how-to-dynamically-change-box-title-in-server-r)

My question is related, but not answered by any of these. I would like to make the `<head><title>...</title></head>` tag reactive, or at least controllable from within an `observeEvent` in `server.R`.

The following does not work, since `ui` can't find `theTitle`, but is the kind of approach I'd hope is possible:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   title = theTitle(),
   textInput("pageTitle", "Enter text:")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    theTitle <- reactiveVal()
    
    observeEvent( input$pageTitle, {
      if(is.null(input$pageTitle)) {
        theTitle("No title yet.")
      } else {
        theTitle(input$pageTitle)
      }
    })
}
```

I've tried making `output$theTitle <- renderText({...})` with the `if..else` logic in that `observeEvent`, and then setting `title = textOutput("theTitle")` in `ui`'s `fluidPage`, but that generates `<div ...>` as the title text, or `<span ...>` if we pass `inline=True` to `renderText`.

In case this clarifies what I'm looking for, the answer would make something equivalent to the *literal* (replacing string variables with that string) `ui` generated by

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    title = "No title yet.",
    ....
)
```

before the user has entered any text in the box; if they have entered "Shiny is great!" into `input$pageTitle`'s box, then we would get the literal

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    title = "Shiny is great!",
    ....
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to write some javascript to take care of that. For example

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "No title yet.",
  textInput("pageTitle", "Enter text:"),
  tags$script(HTML('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("changetitle", function(x) {document.title=x});'))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent( input$pageTitle, {
    title <- if(!is.null(input$pageTitle) && nchar(input$pageTitle)>0) {
      input$pageTitle
    } else {
      "No title yet."
    }
    session$sendCustomMessage("changetitle", title)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This was created following the [How to send messages from the browser to the server and back using Shiny guide](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-send-message.html)

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2021, there is an R package called *shinytitle* that can update the window title from within Shiny's reactive context: [https://cran.r-project.org/package=shinytitle](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinytitle/)