# How to change elements of 'navbarPage' and 'tabPanel' components after loading R Shiny reactive system?

Tags: r, shiny

I am researching how to change elements 'navbarPage' and 'tabPanel' components after loading R Shiny reactive system. Here is a code

```
library(shiny)

# How to change these elements after loading R Shiny reactive system
str_title <- "Title"
str_window_title <- "Window title"
str_cars <- "Cars"
str_iris <- "Iris"

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    title = str_title, 
    windowTitle = str_window_title,
    tabPanel(title = str_cars, fluidPage(fluidRow(dataTableOutput("dt_mtcars")))),
    tabPanel(title = str_iris, fluidPage(fluidRow(dataTableOutput("dt_iris"))))
  ))

# SERVER
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$dt_mtcars <- renderDataTable(datatable(mtcars))
  output$dt_iris <- renderDataTable(datatable(iris))
}

# RUN APP
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The question is how to change values of 'title', 'window_title' for 'navbarPage' component, and 'title' for 'tabPanel' component AFTER loading the Shiny app. For example, add to these names the prefix 'New ' and have the values 'New Title', 'New Window title', 'New Cars', 'New Iris'.

Thanks for sharing your ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution for `windowTitle`, but for the 3 others elements you can use a `textOutput` and reactive values to make the elements change.
Here is an example of changing the elements names after clicking on an action button.

EDIT : found a way to change windowTitle too, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63255351/shiny-how-to-change-the-page-window-title-in-shiny)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("btn", "Change components' names"),
  #javascript code to change window title
  tags$script(HTML('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("changetitle", function(x) {document.title=x});')),
  navbarPage(
    title = textOutput("str_title"), 
    windowTitle = "Window title",
    tabPanel(title = textOutput("str_cars"), fluidPage(fluidRow(dataTableOutput("dt_mtcars")))),
    tabPanel(title = textOutput("str_iris"), fluidPage(fluidRow(dataTableOutput("dt_iris"))))
  ))

# SERVER
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # initialize names
  rv <- reactiveValues(str_title = "Title",
                       str_window_title = "Window title",
                       str_cars ="Cars",
                       str_iris = "Iris")
  
  output$dt_mtcars <- renderDataTable(datatable(mtcars))
  output$dt_iris <- renderDataTable(datatable(iris))
  
  output$str_title <- renderText({
    rv$str_title
  })
  output$str_window_title <- renderText({
    rv$str_window_title
  })
  output$str_cars <- renderText({
    rv$str_cars
  })
  output$str_iris <- renderText({
    rv$str_iris
  })
  
  #change names when button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$btn,{
    print("Change names")
    rv$str_title <- paste0(rv$str_title,"+")
    rv$str_window_title <- paste0(rv$str_window_title,"+")
    rv$str_cars <- paste0(rv$str_cars,"+")
    rv$str_iris <- paste0(rv$str_iris,"+")
    
    session$sendCustomMessage("changetitle", rv$str_window_title )
  })
  

}

# RUN APP
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! It solved particularly the problem. I need to update these elements after Shiny app is loaded. Maybe you know what session handler I can check for this one? I also added "+" to your answer!

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "after shiny app is loaded". In this example you have values at the start, that can be changed after the shiny app is loaded. Can you clarify what you want to do ?

Comment: I need to rename these UI values after the Shiny code is loaded. In your solution, I have to click on the button to do this. In my app, this should be done automatically after app is loaded.

Comment: Just use `observe` instead of `observeEvent` and it will do this

Comment: If change to "observe" I get => "Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)"

Comment: What if you use `observeEvent(1, { ...` instead of  `observeEvent(input$btn, { ...` ?

Comment: I found another way - I process it via "renderUI" component. When app is loaded reactive system check "selectizeInput" elements and by their id I catched changes in UI elements. Thanks a lot for great advice! I will select your answer as it solved my problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226194/discussion-between-andrii-and-gdevaux).